# Customing buttons in Dialog Box in Firemonkey

Tags: android, button, dialog, firemonkey

I am developing a Multi-Device application in Firemonkey.

In some cases in my app appears a Dialog to confirm some action, like this to confirm exit application (in Spanish):

[image]

I would like to put the text in buttons in Spanish, that is to say, 'Yes' like 'Si' ... How I can do it the easiest way?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Anyone can help me ¿?

Comment: I have already solved my doubt !!! I have created a new Form to represent a Dialog with similar aspect than MessageDialog from image. Thus, I can put the text that I want in each Button and personalize actions for each Button.